Lipschitz function which is surjective on subset implies that the subset is dense
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Lipschitz-function. Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an $(n-1)$-connected subset such that $f(A) = \mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to show that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is dense.
First, one can assume w.l.o.g. $f(0) = 0$ (by $\tilde f:= f-f(0)$) and second one can assume that the Lipschitz-constant $L$ is $0\leq L < 1$ (by $\tilde f := \frac{f}{2L}$).
But now I have no good idea how to proof the claim. Maybe the Banach-Fixed-Point-Theorem (BFPT) now could be helpful but I don't see how. By BFPT all sequences $(x_n)$ with $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ arbitrary and $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$ converge to $0$.
Also, I don't see if there would be e.g. any surjective Lipschitz-map $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ (I think in case only continuous there is such a map).
Does anyone know some reference or a proof of this? Is there maybe a generalization to arbitrary metric spaces?

The claim is not true.
For example, let $n=1$
$$ A = (-\infty,0] \cup [1,\infty).$$
The function $f(x)$ which is $x$ if $x<0$, $0$ if $x\in [0,1]$, and $x-1$ if $x\geq 1$ is certainly Lipschitz and surjective. But $A$ is not dense.
What am I missing?

Oh, yes thank you! I forgot to assume, that $A$ has to be $\mathrm{connected}$.

The claim is still not true. Put $A={x:|x|\geq 1}$ and $f(x)=x(|x|-1)$

Kostya_I's counterexample is not Lipschitz at large scales, but still one can easily use his idea (same $A$) to make a connected counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Just send the open unit disk to the origin and slide all points towards the origin. You may want to spend some more time thinking about what you actually want to ask.

Indeed, I guess I need to correct it to $x(|x|-1)/|x|$.

@Kostya_I I think the assumption on the connectedness of $A$ should be even more stronger, namely that $A$ is $(n-1)$-connected. Thank you for your counterexample.

@psl2Z, there's no reason whatsoever for what you want to hold. In particular, you can easily modify the above example for $A$ to be contractible. Let the map preserve each coordinate slice ${x_1=a}$, be the identity map for $a\leq 0$ and for $a>0$, take a version of the above map, with the radius of the excluded ball depending on $a$ and growing from $0$ to $1$ as $a$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$.
